# Copy 'N' key value pairs from one python dictionary to another

Tags: python, dictionary

> def func(x):
>
> ```
> a = {} #empty dict
> b = somefunc() # This returns a dictionary with key value pairs
> for i in range(0,x):
>   # copy any one key value pair from b to a
>   # delete it from b
> ```

This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: I can show you what all I have tried

Comment: should be straightforward. Post what you have currently.

Comment: show us what you tried and also expected input and expected output, it always better for us, instead of reading the whole crap

Comment: Without more information it sounds like this might be a job for the heapq module...(?)

Comment: leave a comment before downvoting. :| atleast would help in where I am going wrong..

Comment: @helloV: I think I am more clear now

Comment: copy one key from a, means any random???

Comment: @bi0s.kidd0. You actually made your question much worse with your last edit by removing all the context.

Comment: @bi0s.kidd0 check my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [popitem](https://docs.python.org/release/3.4.2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) to extract an arbitrary item from a dict:

```
x = 5
a = {}
b = dict(enumerate('ABCDEFGHIJKLM'))

while x > 0:
    try:
        key, value = b.popitem()
    except KeyError:
        break
    else:
        a[key] = value
        x -= 1

print(a)
print(b)
```

output:

```
{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E'}
{5: 'F', 6: 'G', 7: 'H', 8: 'I', 9: 'J'}
```

**NB**:

Despite what the above output suggests, there is no guarantee that the items will be extracted in any particular order.

Answer (score 0):

```
python 2x

import random
a = {} #empty dict
b = somefunc() # This returns a dictionary with key value pairs
b_key = b.viewkeys()
for x in range(0,x)
    element = random.choice(b_key)
    a[element] = b[element]
    del b[element]
```